# Orientation on the boundary

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, orientation

If $M$ is an oriented without boundary manifold, and $\mu$ is it volume form, is true that the boundary of $M\times [0,1]$ is $ M \cup M$, right? It is true also that the orientantion on the boundary is $\mu$ for the superior part, If I can say this way, and $-\mu$ for the inferior part?

Comment: For the first part: technically, $\partial (M\times [0,1])=M\times\{0,1\}=(M\times\{0\})\cup (M\times\{1\})$. Which is indeed the same as $M\coprod M$. However, in that way it hints to the following general result: if $\partial M=\emptyset$, then $\partial (M\times N)=M\times\partial N$.

Comment: @G. how about the orientation?

Comment: if you use the orientation coming from $\mu$ it will be $M\coprod -M$

Comment: @Spotty, you mean, $\mu$ on $M\times {1},$ and $-\mu$ on $M\times {0}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so proper way to formulate is to pick outward pointing vector fields on $\partial M\times I$. Let $\omega=\lambda\times\mu$ be the orientation on $M\times I$.

Then the orientation on $\partial M$ is defined to be $\omega(V_{out},-)$. In one case $\lambda(V_{out})$ is positeve and so we get back $\mu$ in the other is negative and we get $-\mu$ (if you use the standard orientation of $I$ it will be as you said $\mu$ on $M\times\{1\}$.